# Composer unable to resolve sylius/settings-bundle

Tags: symfony, doctrine-orm, composer-php, sylius

I'm unable to resolve the Sylius settings bundle correctly. My application is a Symfony standard application. According to the default json of `Symfony 2.4.4` the requirement is doctrine/doctrine-bundle `~1.2`

My current json:
https://gist.github.com/Rvanlaak/f627a73a8d431600f8ba

**Resolving sylius/settings-bundle `~0.9` gives me the following error:**

```
- Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle == 1.2.0.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0].
- Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-bundle 1.3.x-dev
- sylius/settings-bundle v0.9.0 requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.9.*@dev -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[v0.9.0].
- sylius/settings-bundle 0.10.x-dev requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.10.*@dev -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[0.10.x-dev].
- sylius/resource-bundle v0.9.0 requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.3@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0-beta1].
- sylius/resource-bundle 0.10.x-dev requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.3@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.3.0-beta1].
- Conclusion: don't install doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.3.0-beta1
- Installation request for sylius/settings-bundle ~0.9 -> satisfiable by sylius/settings-bundle[0.10.x-dev, v0.9.0].
```

**Changing my doctrine/doctrine-bundle to ~1.3@dev or 1.2.0 gives the error:**

```
- The requested package doctrine/doctrine-bundle == 1.2.0.0 could not be found.
```

**And therafter require sylius/settings-bundle dev-master gives the error:**

```
- Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.3.x-dev, v1.2.0].
- Can only install one of: doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0, 1.3.x-dev].
- sylius/resource-bundle 0.10.x-dev requires doctrine/doctrine-bundle ~1.3@dev -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[1.3.x-dev].
- sylius/settings-bundle dev-master requires sylius/resource-bundle 0.10.*@dev -> satisfiable by sylius/resource-bundle[0.10.x-dev].
- Installation request for sylius/settings-bundle dev-master -> satisfiable by sylius/settings-bundle[dev-master].
- Installation request for doctrine/doctrine-bundle v1.2.0 -> satisfiable by doctrine/doctrine-bundle[v1.2.0].
```

So to me it looks like the dependencies contradict eachother. Is Symfony standard edition unable to resolve the sylius/settings-bundle ?

**EDIT**

After removing the following bundles composer actually resolves correctly

```
    "lexik/form-filter-bundle" : "~2.0",
    "knplabs/knp-paginator-bundle" : "~2.3",
    "liip/imagine-bundle" : "<1.0.x-dev",
    "raulfraile/ladybug-bundle" : "~1.0",
    "simplethings/entity-audit-bundle" : "~0.5",
    "knplabs/knp-snappy-bundle" : "~1.1",
    "fpn/tag-bundle": "~0.9"
```

Answer (score 1):

Sylius dependencies are a complete mess these days (it is a pre-alpha release). There is no good solution at the moment, but if you use

```
"minimum-stability": "dev",
"prefer-stable": true,
```

in your `composer.json` you probably will get what you expect.

That installs *Doctrine 1.3.0@dev*, that is not compatible with *Symfony 2.4*. So Doctrine code generators (`app/console doctrine:...`) will implode, but *Sylius* will work.

As I said, at the moment there's not an optimal solution, maybe with *Symfony 2.5*.

Comment: I do already make use of the composer settings as you mentioned, but that did not solve the problem. Removing all my custom bundles does resolve the settings bundle, so the problem lies in one of those (see my edit)

Comment: So I think one of those bundles you posted is requiring `Doctrine 1.2.0.0` and it's in conflict with the `Sylius` dependency (1.3). I can't see an easy solution...

Comment: In one of my first attempts composer indeed was able to resolve, but after installing all vendor packages composer was unable to complete the default symfony `post-install-cmd` scripts with the error:

PHP Fatal error:  Class 'Doctrine\ORM\Tools\Console\Command\ClearCache\QueryRegionCommand' not                                     found in /home/scribbr/sites/scribbr/vendor/doctrine/doctrine-bundle/Doctrine/Bundle/DoctrineBu                                    ndle/Command/Proxy/QueryRegionCacheDoctrineCommand.php on line 29

Answer (score 0):

Set all Sylius bundles to version 0.9. And you have no coflicts

Comment: Already was on v0.9 of both `sylius/settings-bundle` and `sylius/resource-bundle`. Symfony Standard is still too dependent on `doctrine/doctrine-bridge v1.2`